# mysql 5.7 procedure syntax error when using not exists

Tags: mysql

this is a procedure to get serialNo.  i  use "if not exists" to determine whether a key exists, but it failed :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `pro_GetSysSerialnumber`;
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_GetSysSerialnumber(IN sName varchar(255), IN sTenantId int)
BEGIN
  if not exists(select 1 from sys_serialnumber where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`) then
      insert into sys_serialnumber (`name`, `next`, `tenantId`) values (`sName`,1 ,`sTenantId`);
  end if;
  update sys_serialnumber set `next`=`next` + 1 where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`;
  select `Id`, `Name`, `next` - 1 as `next`, `tenantId` from sys_serialnumber where `name` = `sName` 
     and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`;
END
```

error:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `pro_GetSysSerialnumber`
> OK
> 时间: 0.378s


CREATE PROCEDURE pro_GetSysSerialnumber(IN sName varchar(255), IN sTenantId int)
BEGIN

    if not exists(select 1 from sys_serialnumber where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`) then
        insert into sys_serialnumber (`name`, `next`, `tenantId`) values (`sName`,1 ,`sTenantId`)
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
> 时间: 0.189s
```

if i remove the "not" in line 4, the script will success:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `pro_GetSysSerialnumber`;

CREATE PROCEDURE pro_GetSysSerialnumber(IN sName varchar(255), IN sTenantId int)
BEGIN

    if   exists(select 1 from sys_serialnumber where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`) then
        insert into sys_serialnumber (`name`, `next`, `tenantId`) values (`sName`,1 ,`sTenantId`);
    end if;
  update sys_serialnumber set `next`=`next` + 1 where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`;
    select `Id`, `Name`, `next` - 1 as `next`, `tenantId` from sys_serialnumber where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`;
END
```

success info:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `pro_GetSysSerialnumber`
> OK
> 时间: 0.377s


CREATE PROCEDURE pro_GetSysSerialnumber(IN sName varchar(255), IN sTenantId int)
BEGIN

    if   exists(select 1 from sys_serialnumber where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`) then
        insert into sys_serialnumber (`name`, `next`, `tenantId`) values (`sName`,1 ,`sTenantId`);
    end if;
  update sys_serialnumber set `next`=`next` + 1 where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`;
    select `Id`, `Name`, `next` - 1 as `next`, `tenantId` from sys_serialnumber where `name` = `sName` and `TenantId`=`sTenantId`;
END
> Affected rows: 0
> 时间: 0.189s
```

that is weird. any ideals?

Comment: i have to move the exists part into where condition:

Comment: Both work fine for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ogVBV8ZsgpDhaYVhbBMvP/0